# How to execute functions remotely on micropython

Tags: python-3.x, micropython

I am currently experimenting with making a debugging interface to a Micropython implementation running on a NIOS2 processor. It is a very rudimentary way of during it by only sending and receiving register write or read commands to/from the device over ethernet.

However, I've got the bright idea that it could be nice if I, with a decorator, could set a whole function to be executed on the device. By sending the entire source code to the device and then uses `exec()`.

This works just fine.
But I ran into the problem with function arguments. If the argument is an already created object how do I get this data to the device? Pickle does not exist in the version of Micropython I'm stuck at using.

I've found that getting the `__dict__` information is the way to go. I am though stuck at how to create an object in micropython without running its `__init__()` method.
IE the object must not be initialized twice since it will corrupt itself.

Is this possible to do?

Regards

Comment: So... You're effectively trying to figure out how to execute arbitrary code remotely?... 

Comment: @CoolBots. That's one way to put it though not entirely correct. I am trying to mimic what pickle does. and send data between two different Python interpreters. So not exactly arbitrary code, I send the information of the code, and then I need to reconstruct it remotely only, Not execute it.